# How easy it is or How easy is it

Tags: questions, exclamations

The actual sentence goes like this:

How easy it is to integrate the two applications? or How easy is it to integrate the two applications?

To my understanding 'How easy it is' wrong if used as a question. So, please clarify.

Comment: Shouldn't a link to the original question be provided if this is a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. "*How easy it is*" is incorrect if used as a question. "*How easy is it*" would be correct for use in a question.

Answer (score 0):

*"How easy it is..."* is more of wonder or exclamation. Probably useful for a rhetoric question. 
*"How easy is it..."* is better for a question.